# Generate Antlr Parse Tree

Tags: python, parsing, antlr, grammar, parse-tree

I am trying to generate the Antlr parse tree. This is a sample grammar which I got from the web.

```
grammar Hel;
hi : 'hello' ID ;         
ID : [a-z]+ ;             
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

I tried the following code in Jupyter notebook to generate the Parse tree.

Please let me know how to fix it.

```
from antlr4 import *
from HelLexer import HelLexer
from HelParser import HelParser


input = InputStream('hello jgt')
lexer = CoDalogLexer(input)
stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
parser = HelParser(stream)
tree = parser.hi()
```

How do I generate the parse tree? How Do I access the elements of the tree?

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't explain what went wrong. `tree` should contain the parse tree.

Comment: How Do I access the elements of the tree?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing elements in a parse tree is simple and when you look at your generated classes it should become obvious. A parse tree has a `children` property or method that allows to access all parse rule contexts that have been created for the found elements during parsing. For convenience there are special accessors that ease getting to specific child contexts. In your example you will see an ID() function on your `HiParseContext` which gives you a context with details for the matched ID token (e.g. location in the input, token type, token text and more). Just look at the generated and the runtime source code to see what's possible.